# Como mostrar el error creado en Express en una aplicación cliente con axios

Tags: javascript, express, axios

Tengo lo siguiente, he creado una aplicación sencilla de ejemplo de una API con express y una aplicación cliente usando axios para realizar los llamados a la API, lo que no logro obtener en el cliente en si es el error que defino el genérico si, pero el que defino no, en la API voy a poner código de la API primero el controlador

```
exports.start = async (req, resp) => {
let query = '';

if(req.body.name && req.body.word){
    if(req.body.name.length >= 2 && req.body.word.length >= 2){
        const values = [
            req.body.name,
            req.body.word
        ];
    
        query = DBSentences.DML_S_STUSER; //sentencia sql (un simple SELECT)
    
        db.DBExecQuery_NoSend(query, true, true, values[0], resp, async (data) => {
            if(data.length > 0){
                resp.json({
                        ok: match,
                        token: "xXSi"
                });
            }
            else{
                resp.status(400).json({error: 'los valores no son correctos.'});
            }       
        });
    }
    else{
        resp.status(400).json({error: 'los valores no son correctos.'});
    }
}
else{
    resp.status(400).json({error: 'los valores no son correctos.'});
}
```

};

Ahora las rutas

```
const express = require('express');
const ctrlGet = require('../controllers/controllerPost');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/startIn/', ctrlGet.start);

module.exports = router;
```

el server

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

const routes = require('./routes/routes');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3030;

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', routes);
```

El cliente

```
const callAPI = async (name, word) => {
    let url = `http://localhost:3030/API/startIn/`;

    const login = await axios.post(url, {name: name, word: word})
                            .catch(e => {
                                console.log('error: ', e);
                                //Aqui deberia imprimir que es error 400 mas el texto mas 'los valores no son correctos.'
                            });
    if(login){
        setLogin(login.data);
    }
}
```

En si cuando se realiza una petición con parámetros erróneos o que no están en la base de datos, en el console.log dentro del catch solo aparece el mensaje

[image: pestaña console de Herramients del desarrollador del navegador]

Pero en la pestaña de red si captura el mensaje

[image: pestaña Red de Herramients del desarrollador del navegador]

Como se hace para capturar el mensaje que se definió en el error y mostrarlo en el cliente, no solo ver el error 400 que retorna si no el mensaje definido, espero me haya echo entender jeje, y gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener la respuesta del error usando `e.response`

```
const login = await axios.post(url, {name: name, word: word})
                        .catch(e => {
                            console.log('error: ', e);
                            console.log('response',e.response);
                        });
```

Mas especificamente puedes usar:

- `e.response.data` para obtener el contenido
- `JSON.parse(e.response.data)` si la respuesta es json y deseas procesar el contenido
- `e.response.status` para obtener el valor del estado HTTP

https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

Comment: gracias F.Igor, jaja la verdad esperaba que al hacer console.log('error: ', e); me mostrara un objeto y sus propiedades, ahora me surge la duda de porque no imprimió el error como un objeto, pero muchas gracias por responder

Comment: Solo es poque el objeto tiene implementado `.toString()` y su implementacion es un mensaje generico `Request failed with...`

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors), si obtienes un response del servidor con un código distinto a 200, entonces el error tendrá una propiedad response, por lo que si imprimes esas propiedad deberías ser capaz de ver la información de error que envías desde el servidor.

```javascript
const callAPI = async (name, word) => {
  let url = `http://localhost:3030/API/startIn/`;

  const login = await axios.post(url, {name: name, word: word})
    .catch(e => {
      if (error.response) {
        //Aqui deberia imprimir que es error 400 mas el texto mas 'los valores no son correctos.'
        console.log('error: ', e.response);
      }
    });
}
```